# How can I port this to objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I wanted to know if is it possible to port exactly this piece of code to objective-c. If that's the case how can I set the `fileprivate(set) lazy` in Objective C? I can't find anything about it, I'm expecting to replace the background of a UITableView when it is empty

```
fileprivate(set) lazy var emptyStateView: UIView = {
        guard let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("EmptyState", owner: nil, options: [:])?.first as? UIView  else {
            return UIView()
        }
        return view
    }()
```

Comment: Why not just expose this to Obj-C?

Comment: Tbh if it were up to me I would change the whole project to swift but it doesn't depend on me :C sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approximate idiom in objective-c would be to declare the property read-only in the `.h` file:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) UIView* emptyStateView;
```

Then in the `.m` file, do something like

```
@synthesize emptyStateView = _emptyStateView;

- (UIView*)emptyStateView {
  if (_emptyStateView == nil) {
    // Code to instantiate _emptyStateView
  }
  return _emptyStateView;
}
```